# Язык "С" сложней чем Java ?

Tags: c, java

Доброй ночи ! Коллеги так вышло что сам я пишу на Java но нам кидают очень различные проекты, и в понедельник должен прийти проект (связан с сетевой защитой) для долгосрочной поддержки и баг-фикса который написан на чистейшем "Си" (так нам сказали) типа вспоминайте "Си-шку", а я хоть и окончил ВУЗ но изучал с самого начала php потом Java (даже немного C# после Java), а вот с чистым "Си" как-то не приходилось встречатся и вот дкмаю занятся изучением этого "Си" или идти работу искать так как пока проектов на Java у нас нет !
На первый взгляд вроде простой язык без ООП, а там кто его знает !!!
Всем большая благодарность кто осмелится ответить хоть строчкой ...

Comment: Более опытные коллеги меня отговаривают от этой идеи с "Си", говорят что человеку познавшему ООП и автоматическое управление памятью, чистый "Си" будет большой проблемой !!!

Comment: Си более низкоуровневый, значит проще выстрелить себе в ногу (особенно если начинал с высокоуровневых ЯП). С другой стороны это позволяет в некоторых случаях писать более оптимальный код (если ты джедай :). С ещё более другой стороны Java, если ещё неправильно готовить (а знающие люди утверждают что правильно её готовят редко), превращается в адового, сводящего с ума, монстра. А с совсем уж другой стороны жабакодеров гораздо больше чем сишников, можно предположить что спрос на адекватных сишников выше. В общем есть смысл попробовать, хотя-бы для расширения сознания, а вдруг получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Oleg_Samitch](/users/16741/oleg_samitch) Ваши более опытные коллеги достойны сочувствия. Си -- простой, но элегантный язык низкого уровня. Что может быть непривычно после java -- ручное управление памятью (выделил динамически -- не забудь освободить и не пренебрегай использованием инструментов для отслеживания этого процесса) и (что важно для чтения чужого кода) массированного использования побочных эффектов. Ну про отсутствие ООП-мифологии Вы и сами знаете.

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо вам за ответ ! Тоесть вы не считаете что Джаверу перейти на Си будет очень сложно ?

Comment: @Oleg_Samitch хотелось бы ответить "да", но ответ -- "не знаю". Я начинал изучение программированию с языка ассемблера, и, соответственно, для меня в Си не было ничего странного. Это с одной стороны. А с другой -- современный Си -- язык, где безопасности конструкций уделяется гораздо больше внимания, чем в K&R Си. Ну и то, что java, как-никак, один из потомков Си -- тоже должно облегчить задачу.

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо за ответ ...

Comment: @alexlz, "java, как-никак, один из потомков Си" -- это проявляется только в похожем синтаксисе. Больше ничего общего между ними нет.

Comment: @dzhioev ну да. Операция `+` в Си складывает аргументы, а в Java (похоже) -- вычитает? Или что Вы имели в виду под отсутствием общности?

Comment: @alexlz:

* Java — безопасный язык, C — нет.
* В Java есть рефлексия, в C нет.
* В C вы можете оценить по коду грубо прикинуть его эффективность (код более-менее прямо отображается на ассемблер), в Java нет.
* В Java есть встроенное в язык безопасное позднее связывание (виртуальные функции), в C — нет.
* В C flow программы везде явный, в Java нет (в любом месте может произойти исключение).
* В Java приветствуется сокрытие данных, в C нет
* В C данные и код обычно разделены, в Java нет (наоборот, приветствуется инкапсуляция данных в классы).

Ну и так далее.

Comment: @VladD Ой.

1. Безопасность. Дискутабельно. Скорее рекламное понятие.

2. Разумеется. В C уже оптимизированный код. Его так просто не расшифруещь. 

3. За исключением локальных оптимизаций.

4. Разумеется.

5. Исключительные ситуации (mem. protection и т.д.), goto, longjump

6. Разумеется.

7. Обсуждаемо. Если Вы запишите данные в файл, а потом (не описывая его в программе) прочитаете, то никакого кода там не будет. (сходно с нарушением принципов ФП во многих ФП-языках -- читать/писать функции нельзя)

Ну и так далее. Вывод -- это разные языки. С не идентичен java. Придётся согласиться

Comment: @alexlz: (1) Не совсем рекламное. В C результат выполнения кода

    i = i++ + ++i;

или там

    ((char*)malloc(1))[100] = 0;

есть UB, то есть код имеет право отформатировать винчестер (и даже [иногда](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) так делает). В Java поведение любого кода регламентировано стандартом.

(2) рефлексию можно эмулировать в C, заведя вручную структуры с метаданными, но она не поддерживается языком.

В общем, я хотел продемонстрировать, что языки не просто _разные_, а _ой-ой-ой как разные_. Список можно продолжать (строки, GC, потоки, содержимое стандартной библиотеки, ...

Comment: @VladD когда оно так делает? Это когда `Of course not`? То, что языки разные -- никто не спорит. Все языки разные. Но C к Java гораздо ближе не только erlang'а, но и фортрана.

Comment: @alexlz: Например, тот самый «of course not». Правильно написанная программа не выполняет эксплоиты.

Насчёт безопасности — я имею в виду не возможность сделать что-то неправильно, а [memory safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_safety).

Answer (score 3):

Ещё одна проблема — указатели, массивы и строки. Они очень похожи в C синтаксически, что часто приводит к недопониманию.

Отдельный пункт — ручное управление памятью и понимание того, что указатель в C (в отличие от ссылки в Java) может указывать на невыделенную, неинициализированную или освобождённую память.

Ещё одно серьёзное отличие: у ресурсов в отсутствие GC появляется *владелец* — сущность (код), ответственная за своевременное освобождение ресурса.

Comment: @VladD Наличие/отсутствие арифметики указателей. В Си это естественное следствие его низкого уровня. Других различий пока не вижу (кроме именно синтаксических -- нет операций `&` и `*`)

    указатель в C (в отличие от ссылки в Java) может указывать на невыделенную, неинициализированную или освобождённую память.

А в отличие от WeakReference?

Comment: @alexlz: Ну, да, естественное отличие, конечно. Однако адресная арифметика всё же специфична для C, соотношения типа `&a[i] = a + i` довольно специфичны и не присутствуют, например, в ассемблере.

Отличие от `WeakReference` состоит в том, что вы не можете, имея указатель, гарантировать его валидность «локально»: вам нужно знать всю логику программы, чтобы уметь доказать/опровергнуть этот факт. С `WeakReference` же ситуация другая: если из него получилась сильная ссылка, то она **гарантировано** валидна, вам не нужно анализировать program flow, чтобы это выяснить.

Comment: @VladD Разумеется слабые ссылки -- они везде слабые ссылки (и созданы для взаимодействия программы с GC, которого в Си изначально не было предусмотрено).

Адресная арифметика -- красивое и машинно-эффективное обобщение индексации (которая появилась в конце 50х вроде). В ассемблере не присутствуют потому, что там все эти механизмы должны быть расписаны до инструкций. Кстати,

     &a[i] == a + i
     &i[a] == a + i

И ещё никто не вспомнил про селекторы структур в K&R C (там вроде селекторы полей не привязывались к структуре, хотя могу и перепутать за давностью).

Comment: @alexlz: Угу, меня всегда удивляло, что `i[a]` компилируется. Как мне кажется, это нужно лишь для того, чтобы сказать «а вы знали такое?», и не имеет вообще никакого практического применения.

Впрочем, в остальном C очень милый и изящный язык.

А что такое селекторы структур? Какой синтаксис и что это даёт? (Я правда не в курсе.)

Comment: @VladD ну термин скорее из другого языка (хотя, может, и в Си применялся). Имена полей. 

    struct a {int a1, a2};
    b = a.a1;

Ежели не путаю, в K&R Си имена a1, a2 должны быть уникальны и могли применяться к любым структурам. Но дальше -- не помню. Откуда ноги растут понятно -- "фиктивные секции" ассемблеров для архитектур с базовыми регистрами, где имена задавали смещения относительно базы.

Сейчас такой подход используется в haskell.

Comment: @VladD а равноправие a[i] и i[a] -- следствие адресной арифметики. `a[i]` тождественно `*(a+i)`. Соответственно `i[a]` тождественно `*(i + a)`. "От перестановки мест слагаемых ...". Процессоры были слабенькими, память маленькой, и трансляторы, соответственно, не шибко сложными.

Comment: @alexlz: Всё равно непонятно, откуда взялась коммутативность. С точки зрения адресов

    a + i = &a + i * sizeof(*a)

Так что никакой перестановки слагаемых. Тем более, `a + a` ведь не компилируется. Так что компилятору по-любому необходимо просматривать типы, и иметь закодированный специальный случай:

* `число + число = простая сумма`
* `указатель + число = значение указателя + число * размер элемента`
* `число + указатель = указатель + число`
* `указатель + указатель и остальное = ошибка`

Answer (score 2):

Внесу и свои 5 копеек.

Не устаю всем повторять, что Си (именно язык, а не библиотеки и система) прост, как палка и веревка, чем и хорош.

Что использует программа для работы с сетью (сказано про сетевую безопасность), неизвестно. Может чистые RAW-сокеты, может какую-то библиотеку, но кучу RFC вам однозначно придется проштудировать.

Проект-то, хоть в *nix-ах?

Comment: @avp, да проект *никсовый

Answer (score 1):

C и C++ очень сильно отличаются от C# и Java. Насколько знаю, c# разрабатывался Microsoft как ответ Java, и многие вещи, которыми в с/с++ приходится заниматься вручную, в Java и C# обрабатываются сами. Это очень длинное путешествие, если вы решитесь, и "простой багфикс" слету вряд ли получится сделать.

Answer (score 1):

нормальному програмисту сложно переходить между разнотипными языками, например, с java в erlang или haskell. Большой порог вхождения. А между родственными языками - просто.

С чистым си будут три проблемы:

- строки вручную.
- нет многих "удобняшек" (например, такого привычного List, нужно писать или брать что то готовое).
- убирать за собой (GC нет).

Но зато будут плюсы:

- компилируется быстро (если только это майкрософт)
- количество абстракций сильно меньше
- вызывает привыкание.

Comment: Нормальному програмисту по-моему наоборот несложно переходить между языками различными. Учитывая, что Java и Си схожи, то проблем не должно быть.

А вот переход с Java на какой-нить ужас типо хекселя или брейнфака...да...это сложно =D

Comment: @Suvitruf ставить рядом brainfuck и haskell -- это круто. brainfuck к java поближе будет, чем к haskell :)

Хотя, среди кошмарных языков и у haskell'a есть родня. Но уж точно не brainfuck.

Answer (score 1):

Чистый C скорее всего после Java/C# будет очень сложен. В том плане, что нет никакой автоматизации. Даже такие примитивный классы как String будет тяжело сэмулировать.

Когда приходится писать на нем, то я часто матерюсь ибо порой вообще не понятно в чём ошибка. Компиляторы выдают чаще чем в Java/C# какие-то общие ошибки и хрен поймешь где конкретно и почему они возникают.

Но я бы сказал, что поробовать стоит.

Будет очень тяжело с указателями и стрингами (точнее с отсутствием стрингов). Но как не крути в С получаются более эффективные по скорости программы, чем во многих других языках.

Comment: Что касается "тяжело со стрингами" -- так мне понравилось.

А стринги -- это строки или женские трусики? А серьёзней -- да, со строками кодировщику придётся набирать больше. Да и современное доминирование utf8 слабо соответствует практике 70х-80х годов с ascii. (Кстати, а в java -- utf16? Если да, то как там старые программы будут работать с четырёхбайтными символами?)

А что касается ошибок -- я таких проблем не вижу. Хотя не раз замечал, что это просто следствие элементарной небрежности. Первых признак -- программист не обращает внимания на warning'и компилятора.

Comment: @alexlz
> А стринги -- это строки или женские трусики?

Господи, ну когда эта шутка умрет, а?

Comment: @Fike 

    Господи, ну когда эта шутка умрет, а?

скорее всего, когда обсуждение будет вестись на русском языке. А не смешении нижегородского с пиджин-инглиш.

Comment: вообщем всем спасибо, я так понял что будет сложно но всё же нужно попробовать ... Надеюсь в нашем проекте не нужно будет разбиратся с криптографией вдобавок к "Си-шке" !!!

Comment: @alexlz или когда уровень культуры подрастет

Comment: К стати ребята, а не подкините пару умных книг по "Си-шке" ?

Comment: Prata - C Primer Plus. Addison-Wesley Professional. 6-th edition. 2013.

Comment: @Oleg_Samitch так Керниган, Ритчи. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)

@Fike а второе без первого возможно?

Comment: @alexlz
Да, согласен. Такие ошибки это, как правило, небрежность. Только вот современные языки прощают эту небрежность, а С нет. После каждой команды надо перепроверять, а всё ли в порядке. Зарезервировалась ли память, а точно открылся ли файлик, а правильно ли считалась строка... Java/C# сильно упрощают всё это до такой степени, что можно концентрироваться на решение задачи, а не на борьбе с языком...

Comment: @Sharbag, насчет 

    современные языки прощают эту небрежность, а С нет.

это у Вас какой-то пионерский подход.

Неизвестно еще, что более трудоемко -- анализ кодов возврата или грамотно спроектированная обработка исключений. 

При небрежной обработке исключений Вы обречены на бесконечный *рефакторинг*. То-то это слово так часто встречается вместе с термином ООП.

Comment: Ну вообще тут скорее дело привычки. Просто перебираясь с C# на С были у меня такие проблемы.

Comment: @Oleg_Samitch, вспомнил хорошую книжку

[Керниган Б., Пайк Р. Практика программирования](http://bookfi.org/g/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%91.%D0%92.,%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%20%D0%A0.)

но это не учебник и не только Си.